# service broker - poison message - how to handle? how to enable poison messase handling?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dmv, service-broker, troubleshooting

I am getting constantly this error message on service broker:

> POISON MSSAGE - Message Removed from the queue to allow other messages
>   to proceed - ApplicationID: 377411

```
select top 1000
* from junofinance.[dbo].[servicebrokerlog] with(nolock)
order by logdate desc

select top 1000
* from junofinance.[dbo].[servicebrokerlog] with(nolock)
where message NOT LIKE 'POISON MSSAGE - Message Removed from the queue to allow other messages to proceed - ApplicationID: 377411'
order by logdate desc
```

[image]

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- service broker -- having a look
-- v.20171111
--marcello miorelli
----------------------------------------------------
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
SELECT the_server = @@servername
      ,the_database = db_name()
      ,CE.conversation_handle
      ,CE.conversation_group_id
      ,ce.state_desc
      ,ce.far_service
      ,s.name as [Local Service]
      ,ce.far_broker_instance
      ,ce.is_initiator
      ,S.name   AS [Service Name]
      ,SC.name  as [Contract Name]
      ,SQ.name  as [Queue Name]
      ,sq.activation_procedure
      ,sq.is_activation_enabled
      ,sq.is_receive_enabled
      ,sq.is_enqueue_enabled
      ,sq.is_retention_enabled
      ,sq.is_poison_message_handling_enabled
      ,tq.enqueue_time
      ,tq.from_service_name
      ,tq.is_conversation_error
      ,tq.is_end_of_dialog
      ,tq.message_body
      ,tq.message_sequence_number
      ,tq.message_type_name
      ,tq.priority
      ,tq.service_contract_name
      ,tq.to_broker_instance
      ,tq.to_service_name
      ,tq.transmission_status

FROM sys.conversation_endpoints ce

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.services s
             ON ce.service_id = s.service_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.service_queues SQ
             ON S.service_queue_id = SQ.object_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.service_contracts sc
             ON ce.service_contract_id = sc.service_contract_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.transmission_queue TQ
             ON ce.conversation_handle = tq.conversation_handle
```

[image]

as you can see on the picture above I haven't got a poison message handling enabled.
How to enable one???

Can you please help me troubleshoot this `probably a case of poison message` problem in the service broker?

There are lots of invoices coming through, I can't afford to lose anything!

This site below suggests a few interesting things:

[Service Broker Poison Message Handling](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3808556/Service-Broker-Poison-Message-Handling.htm)

there is this question here, but I am still investigating:

[Service Broker: Queue Monitor is dropped after poison message](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21207/service-broker-queue-monitor-is-dropped-after-poison-message)

This is my procedure, please note the generation of the error message above, in the `catch block` inside the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_process_invoice_message]   
AS   
  BEGIN   
      DECLARE @applicationID INT,   
              @dialog_handle VARCHAR(max),   
              @messageType   NVARCHAR(max);   

      WHILE ( 1 = 1 )   
        BEGIN   
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;   

            WAITFOR ( receive TOP (1) @dialog_handle = conversation_handle,   
            @applicationid = message_body, @messageType = message_type_name FROM   
            [dbo].[invoiceTargetQueue] ), timeout 60000;   

            IF( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 )   
              BEGIN   
                  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;   

                  BREAK;   
              END   

            SAVE TRANSACTION MessageReceivedSavepoint;   
            BEGIN try   
                IF ( @messageType = 'http://aifs.co.uk/InvoiceCreationRequest' )   
                  BEGIN   
                      INSERT INTO dbo.servicebrokerlog   
                                  ([message],   
                                   databasename,   
                                   source)   
                      VALUES     ( 'Application ready for invoice creation '   
                                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @applicationID),   
                                   Db_name(),   
                                   'usp_process_invoice_message');   

                      EXEC Usp_ins_invoiceandtransactions   
                        @applicationID;   
                  END   

                IF ( @messageType = 'DEFAULT'   
                      OR @messageType =   
            'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog' )   
                  BEGIN   
                      END conversation @dialog_handle;   

                      INSERT INTO [dbo].[servicebrokerlog]   
                                  (message,   
                                   databasename,   
                                   source)   
                      VALUES     ('CONVERSATION CLOSED BY THE TARGET CH->'   
                                  + Cast(@dialog_handle AS VARCHAR(max)),   
                                  Db_name(),   
                                  'usp_process_invoice_message');   
                  END   

                COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
            END try   

            BEGIN catch   
                IF ( Error_number() = 1205 )   
                  BEGIN   
                      -- DEADLOCK,LETS TRY AGAIN   
                      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION messagereceivedsavepoint  

                      CONTINUE   
                  END   
                ELSE   
                  BEGIN   
                      DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)   
                      DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT   
                      DECLARE @ErrorState INT   
                      DECLARE @ErrorLine INT   
                      DECLARE @errorProc NVARCHAR(126)   
                      DECLARE @errorNum INT   

                      SELECT @ErrorMessage = Error_message(),   
                             @ErrorSeverity = Error_severity(),   
                             @ErrorState = Error_state(),   
                             @errorLine = Error_line(),   
                             @errorProc = Error_procedure(),   
                             @errorNum = Error_number()   

     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;   

                      INSERT INTO [dbo].[servicebrokerlog]   
                                  ([message],   
                                   databasename,   
                                   source)   
                      VALUES     (   
'POISON MSSAGE - Message Removed from the queue to allow other messages to proceed - ApplicationID: '  
+ CAST(@applicationID AS VARCHAR(50)),   
Db_name(),   
'usp_process_invoice_message');   

    --log the error message     
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[servicebrokererrorlog]   
                (errormessage,   
                 errorseverity,   
                 errorstate,   
                 errorline,   
                 errorproc,   
                 errornumber,   
                 databasename)   
    VALUES      ( @ErrorMessage,   
                  @ErrorSeverity,   
                  @ErrorState,   
                  @errorLine,   
                  @errorProc,   
                  @errorNum,   
                  Db_name() );   


END   
END catch   
END --while end   
END
```

Another thing to look at:

```
set nocount on

if object_id('tempdb..#ErrLog') is not null
   drop table #ErrLog

CREATE TABLE #ErrLog (SeqNo bigint identity(1,1) not null,  LogDate datetime, ProcessInfo varchar(50), LogText varchar(max))

INSERT INTO #ErrLog (LogDate,ProcessInfo,LogText)
EXEC sp_readerrorlog

SELECT *
FROM #ErrLog 
ORDER BY LogDate desc, SeqNo desc

drop table #ErrLog
```

this is the only service broker relevant message that I have seen:

> Service Broker login attempt by user 'MYCOMPANY_USA\sqlservice.'
>   failed with error: 'A previously existing connection with the same
>   peer was detected during connection handshake. This connection lost
>   the arbitration and it will be closed. All traffic will be redirected
>   to the previously existing connection. This is an informational
>   message only. No user action is required. State 80.'.  [SERVER:
>   10.31.9.999]

Comment: What error is causing the failure?  It should be in your servicebrokererrorlog table.

Comment: The error is: `The server principal "MYCOMPANYK\sqldbslaveowner" is not able to access the database "JUNOCORE" under the current security context.`

Comment: `MYCOMPANYK\sqldbslaveowner` is the database owner, never had any permissions assigned to it.

Comment: this service broker instance has been working for years.

Comment: Read http://rusanu.com/2006/01/12/why-does-feature-not-work-under-activation/ and http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/ and for an alternative fix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188304(v=sql.105)